# JavaScript Error: "ReferenceError: sprLib is not defined"

Tags: javascript, rest, sharepoint

I need assistance with trying to figure out why I'm getting this error in my code... 
"ReferenceError: sprLib is not defined"
THANK YOU in advance for your help.

```
A segment of my code is...
sprLib.list('DRLs').items({
    listCols: {
        iD:  { dataName:'ID' },
        drlId:    { dataName:'Title' },
        artifactIdCopy:   { dataName:'ArtifactID' },
        assessmentId:   { dataName:'AssessmentIDCopy' },
        dueDate:   { dataName:'TaskDueDate' },
        AOREmails: { dataName:'AOREmails'},
        startDate: { dataName:'Assessment_x0020_ID_x0020_LU_x00'},
        teamMemberEmails: { dataName:'TeamMemberEmails'},
        artifactLink:   { dataName: 'Artifact_x0020_Link'},
        drlItemLink:   { dataFunc:function(objItem) {return '<a href="  ">View</a>}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I got it. I needed to reference (src) a different jquery file. Thank you!